# facing issues in executing Azure vision api

Tags: azure, vision, vision-api

Hello All I am using Azure's vision analyze api to extract text from my documents,

here is the example code for your reference

```
//My main function fi.fullfile is the path of my uploaded document

AzureAnalyzeRequest(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName));
```

analyze function

```
static async void AzureAnalyzeRequest(byte[] byteData)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    // Request headers
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "MyKey");

    // Request parameters
    queryString["language"] = "en";
    queryString["pages"] = "1,2";
    var uri = "https://url-ocr.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.2/read/analyze?" + queryString;
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
}
```

when the above function executed I am getting the error of 400 bad request

but when I tested my api on the below URL

[Azure Vision api](https://uaenorth.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005/console)

it worked fine.

what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- According to this [MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/computervision/3.1/read/read?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)  the api needs a Json object in the following form:

```
{
    "url":""
}
```

- I think you are passing a byte array, you need a Json object which will contain a URL of the image you want to process.
- So here I have created a class called `Poco` which will host the URL variable.

```
 public class Poco
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

- Then I initialized the class and passed the URL then convert that object into a Json object.

```
 Poco p = new Poco();
 p.url = "<URL OF YOUR IMAGE>";
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
   
  // Here we are converting the json string to stringcontent which we can pass to httpclient  
       
 StringContent data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Now all you have to do is call the Api:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<YOURKEY>");
           
var response = client.PostAsync(url, data);

Console.WriteLine(response.Result.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
```

[image]

- If you want to use the byte array of image, then I think the `content-type` header should be `application/octet-stream` according to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/computervision/3.1/read-in-stream/read-in-stream?tabs=HTTP#request-body)

Comment: Yes I know it's almost 14 days since you answered, but I have few question

Comment: can I use url and pass the url of current system for e.g.(D://Folder/Images/xyz.png), I don't think it will work but still

Comment: and if I pass byte array and change content-type will it work?